# "Discussion moved to chat" prevents me from re-finding the question from my "All activity" page

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

Yesterday I had a useful discussion, and when I today wanted to go there again, I could not find the discussion anymore, because a mod moved it to the chat system. I had to google the question that the discussion was about, in order to find the chat summary of it.

I propose that in such an event, my "All activity" or "comments" activity page gets an entry "Comments that moved to chat", clicking on which directs the user to the corresponding chat summary of the discussion.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure it would have worked any better if the comment trail wasn't moved?  I've never seen any conclusive evidence that Google indexes the comments and never knowingly got a hit on my own.  Comments are ephemeral, indexing them is not a feature.  And besides, you would have gotten a hit from the chat url :)

Comment: @hans i would not have needed to use google because the comments would presumably still be linked from my activities page.

Comment: @HansPassant: [Googling for comments works fine for me.](https://www.google.com/search?q=hans+passant+"You%27d+better+keep+an+eye+on+Task+Manager%27s+Processes+tab")

Comment: searching google for comments is a very poor substitute for finding things that would otherwise be linked from my activities page.

Comment: Another workaround is looking at your [chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/34509), if you don't chat otherwise the relevant discussion will be among your "recent" messages. Of course you have to suspect that the discussion had been moved to chat. And anyway your feature-request makes perfect sense.

Comment: It's pity that useful comments are often buried in almost useless chat. Other  stackexchange sites also struggle from this, some to a much larger extent (like physics stackexchange). And yes, I know all that stuff about putting all useful info in answer, but reality is different.

Comment: Some of us can't even get to chat when we need to because it's blocked by our workplace content-control software.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you should receive a notification that your comments were moved to chat, that takes you to the chatroom. Did you not receive a notification on the top bar? At any rate, this is what the 'favorite' function is for; if you want to return to an interesting question or answer, favorite it and you can then have quick access to it under your Favorites tab in your profile.

Comment: @HansPassant Nobody treats comments as ephermal, they're as important as the questions and answers themselves.  Its rare I find a difficult question where reading comments on the answers isn't a necessity for a correct solution.  Its time to kill that old line and treat comments as first class entities, the idea of them being ephermal failed miserably.

Comment: @TylerH if I received such a notification, I must have missed it. I was more certain that maybe the answer on which the comments were attached was deleted by the author, than the comments being moved to chat.

Comment: (maybe a mod could move this discussion to the chat so that everyone can convince themselfs what notifications are sent when and where?)

Comment: One person downvoted this question... maybe the poor thing who will have to implement the new feature.

Comment: @GabeSechan: _"Nobody treats comments as ephermal, they're as important as the questions and answers themselves."_ They're not, and if you're not treating them as such then that's your fault and nobody else's. Did you integrate the information you found in those comments into the answers, by editing? If not, you're part of the problem, not of the solution!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition sometimes the answer author disagrees with the comments and won't allow the edition into the answer.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition When its one person, you're right.  When its a substantial (majority) of the userbase, its time to revisit assumptions to adapt to current use cases.  The number of people who treat comments as ephermal is probably single digits.  I am part of the solution-  the solution is not making comments ephermal when the userbase doesn't want that and has said so loudly by their use.

Comment: @Gabe: What a silly approach. The SO model was deliberately cultivated so as to move _away_ from that messy Experts Exchange model. If you don't like it you're free to go someplace else, but claiming that only a "single digit" number of people use the site properly is absurd.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition You can go ahead and keep using the site in any way you want.  In the meantime, I'm going to use it in the way the majority uses it.  If you think that the majority of users have ever looked deep enough at the website to know that comments are supposed to be ephermal, you're delusional.  90% of users have never read any of the documentary pages, and that's a conservatively low estimate

Comment: @GabeSechan: Wildly making up alternative facts doesn't aid your argument!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I'm not in an argument.  You're assuming that a website with millions of users have people who actually read all of the fine print.  That goes against every bit of usability research ever done, not to mention the simple fact that nobody is actually following the rules.  You even admit that the rules aren't being followed by saying I'm part of the problem-  the fact that there's a problem admits I'm right.  The solution is to not use a broken usecase like ephermal comments-  if comments are useful, they're first class.  If not remove them.  Anything else is bad design.

Comment: Why are massive comment threads like this tolerated in meta but not in normal stack? - perhaps a better comment/chat like UX is needed.